Is it possible to re-orient my world axis to the "ground" of my model? rather than rotating my model to match the world axis
Currently the construction plane is vertical to the base of my model. I'm trying to have the construction plane on the base instead.
I downloaded this model from Google earth and I plan to re-upload it later. Rotating the model make the it "floating" on Google earth. 

Did you apply the rotation after you rotated it in Blender? Ctrl-A > Rotation in Object mode with everything selected.

You can't move or rotate the world axis.

why not rotating the model to make it match the global axis?

If you do not want to rotate the model, there is nothing you can do. The world orientation cannot be changed. And it would not make much sense either. A scene can have multiple objects, not just a single one. Everything based on world coordinates (not just objects, modifiers, constraints etc. as well) would change just because you wanted to avoid rotating one object.

There is no "hyperworld" or something similar containing the world. Without such wrapping frame of reference it doesn't make a difference if you rotate an object to align with the world or rotate the world to align with the object. It's like rotating a house to have the door open without touching the door - if there's no ground or other frame of reference, there's no difference between the two. Regarding your export/import problem, maybe you could parent the object to an empty and rotate that empty?
